# Failed to find Node for given afront point - Poly2Tri

Tags: c#, triangulation

I am want to cut a hole in a polygon:

```
|-----------------------|
|                       |
|      |------|         |
|      |      |         |
|      |------|         |
|                       |
|-----------------------|
```

The outer has the following coords (double):

```
-0,76 ; -1,5
1,86  ; -1,5
-0,76 ; 1,5
1,86  ; 1,5
```

The inner coords (double) are:

```
0,65 ; -0,66
1,57 ; -0,66
0,65 ; 0,75
1,57 ; 0,75
```

I want to use for this Poly2Tri an created a Polygon with the first four points.

```
PolygonPoint[] pts = new PolygonPoint[shape.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < shape.Length; i++)
{
  pts[i] = new PolygonPoint((shape[i].X), (shape[i].Y));
  points.Add(shape[i]);
}
Polygon p = new Polygon(pts);
```

After that I added a hole with the second four points.

```
p.AddHole(new Polygon(ptsO));
```

Now I called:

```
P2T.Triangulate(p);
```

I get the following exception: Failed to find Node for given afront point

How do I fix this exception?

Comment: What's the full stacktrace and error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this library, but the outer 4 points are not in counterclockwise order as you specified them.  Instead, they cross,  where the grey line connects point3 back to point0:

[image]

Try adding them in counterclockwise order instead.  You may need to create the inner loop in clockwise order, depending on Poly2Tri's conventions.

**Update**

Just found some documentation [here](http://sites-final.uclouvain.be/mema/Poly2Tri/):

[image]

> 3. Input/Output
>
> Simple Polygon outer bounary vertices oriented in counter clockwise direction.
>
> [snip]
>
> Here are the all vertices for holes oriented in clockwise direction;